# Three column design HTML

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to recreate a web page with a three column design like the page below, but i'm having some trouble.  I've tried using nested divs, but the code does not seem to be working for some reason.  Here's a snippet of the html and css code

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>
<h1>The CIS 4004 Newsletter</h1>    
</header>

<div id="wrapper" role="main">

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#test">Test link</a>; </li> 
</ul>
</nav>

<article>
<div class="inner">
    <h2>Test header</h2>
<p>Just some test text.
</p>
 </div>
 </article>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css code is here

```
 #wrapper {

        border: 1px solid black;
        position:relative;
        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        overflow:hidden;
    }


    nav{
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
        border: 2px solid black;
        position:relative;
    }


    article.inner {
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px:
    border: 2px solid red;
    }
```

Here's an image of the web page [image: http://i58.tinypic.com/4rt43o.png]

http://jsfiddle.net/2yjhp/

Comment: What's not working? Your code definitely doesn't make anything like that image.

Comment: This is what you've done so far: http://jsbin.com/jeqoz/1/edit what's your exact issue?

Comment: For example, I was attempting to change the color of the center box to red to see if the code was working.  As you can see on jsbin though, it isn't working.

Comment: Take a look here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

Comment: @user3558122 We will NOT do your homework for you. Exact link to the homework assignment here http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cis4004/sum2014/Homework%20Assignment%202.ppt (It downloads a powerpoint).

Comment: @VikingBlooded I never said such a thing, and that was not my intention. Based on the code provided, the person who asked the question hasn't really tried anything before asking. It just comes off as "write my homework for me". That's all.

Comment: My original post isn't asking anyone to do my homework nor am I trying to hide the fact that this is a homework assignment as you can see from my screenshot, the class number is clearly listed.

Comment: I only provided a small portion of my code for obvious reasons.  As I pointed out, i've been attempting to use the nested div method, which is also listed in our notes on that same website, and i'm having some issues with it.  Learn to read.

Comment: I'm not intending to be rude or anything along those lines. If you post more code that you have tried you would be more likely to have people help, and avoid the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple template

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Left Content</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle Content</div>
    <div class="right">Right Content</div>
</div>
```

---CSS---

```
div.wrapper {width: 1000px; margin: 0px auto;}
div.left {width: 250px; float: left;}
div.middle{float: left;}
div.right{width: 250px; float: left;}
```

Comment: You forgot a closing quote, I adjusted it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whether your designing a three column layout or a two column layout the key thing to remember  is to floating all the columns in the same direction (left) and adjusting there width accordingly. There is no need to use nested div.
eg:

```
       cloumnone{float: left;
                 width: 33%;}
```

similary for other two cloumns...